# Add column to show a row number in the PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

At first, I am a noobie in databases and I learn this area now. So, maybe it's very easy but I don't know how all same.
I have an existing database where as primary key we use `UUID`. But now, I need to add an order number for each row (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 and etc), i.e. the number value is not important, it requires only to it will be unique for each row and generates automatically.
I know that it's bad solution in the relation model but I can't change a primary key type by some reasons, so I need add yet column that will be anologue as if we used an Integer primary key with `auto_increment`.
How can I make it? I tried to find a solution but everywhere says about a primary key only.

Comment: is it compulsory to add column in table , if not then you can generate row_number using t-sql function row_number which will be unique for each row

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi, sorry, can you explain more details? I really bad know SQL and databases generally. I need a column because our program supports only tables (without views and functions). So, I can't use any function to get a something from the database.

Comment: If you want to just display the row_number in query output then you can use t-sql function row_number rather than adding to DB
let me know your purpose for row number then i can explain you better

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi, this number requires to our users can input it in our VCS when they will close tasks. And due to our Postgres data provider limits I need to add a real column.

Comment: You mean to say the row number will be entered by users or you need it to be auto generated?

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi, it will be auto generate in the database. Our program shows this number to the user. And he can input it after in our VCS service (it's a separate service).

Comment: ok then you should use the current timestamp which will be unique for each record
extract(epoch from now())

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi, yeah, thank you! I should have guessed.